# Linked non static image in Gmail signatures

Tags: gmail, email-signature

I'm trying to use an email signature that has a “rotating” logo.

Each month the logo changes (like Google's “doodle”, kind of).

Instead of changing the signature of my colleagues every month, I'd rather use an image that points to a web URL, and the signature changes automagically without users' concern.

And it works, but only sometimes.

The question is **why it doesn't always reflect the image on the server?** And how to force using linked images in the signature?

At other times, a colleague's signature's image just remains indefinitely, while other's signature's image reflects the image on the server.

Notes:

- I'm changing the signature via Gmails' web interface → *Settings*.
- I test the signature on new emails (already-opened emails' images are preloaded by Google to circumvent tracking, so just reloading the same email doesn't reflect reality).
- Me and my colleagues all share the same domain (our emails are xxx@our-domain.org).

Comment: Are you using Google Apps for Business to receive mail?

Comment: me and myu colleagues use google-apps-business, but our other correspondents use on various email providers and email clients

Comment: I expect that the image is being cached by whatever client is reading it at the time and, since the URL is static, it's just displaying what it's already got in its cache.

Comment: You could _potentially_ try to encode the image(s) into a CSS file. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1124149/198836) for details on CSS image embedding.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, having "rotating" logo that automatically updates on messages sent previously is not possible.

From [Images Now Showing - Gmail Official Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html)

> Instead of serving images directly from their original external host
>   servers, Gmail will now serve all images through Google’s own secure
>   proxy servers.

To update the logo on messages being sent could be done by using an HTML editor that allows to set a image by a URL and that it doesn't cache it.